# How does srckeep affect the underlying disk frame?

Tags: r, disk.frame

I have a disk frame with these columns

```
key_a
key_b
key_c
value
```

Say the disk frame is 200M rows and I'd like to group it by key_b. Additionally, I want to keep the underlying disk frame in tact and unchanged so I could later on join it to something else on key_c or aggregate it on key_a. I'm concerned that srckeep affects the underlying disk frame.

Will either of these work? If so, can I expect one to be faster than the other?

```
  df %>% 
  srckeep("value", "key_b") %>%
  group_by(key_b) %>% 
  summarize(avg = mean(value)) %>% 
  collect
```

```
  df[
    keep = c("value", "key_b" 
    .(avg = mean(value)),
    .(key_b)
    ]
```

How will either of these aggregations affect the underlying disk frame? I had an experience earlier where I assigned an aggregation to a variable, and then ran `delete(aggregation`, but it deleted the entire disk frame.

Comment: `disk.frame` by default uses `data.table`.  So, it may be more natural to use data.table syntax as it can be faster

Comment: That's awesome. Does that mean I can change a disk frame on reference?

Comment: I assume  it is the case.  Please do check the vignettes

Comment: Actually dplyr syntax is much better supported atm due to my bandwidth limitations. You can't really change the disk.frame on disk unless you overwrite it. I need to make this more clear in the docs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply an operation, it doesn't change the underly disk.frame at all!

`srckeep` only affects what gets used! It loads only those columns in `srckeep` in memory when doing the processing. Again, it doesn't affect the underlying data at all.

Unless you do `write_disk.frame(some_other_diskf, "to/location_of_disk.frame.df", overwrite=TRUE)` which will overwrite the old disk.frame.

The disk.frame is always on disk. You can see where it is with `attr(diskf, "path")`